# ERROR: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, spring-boot, build.gradle, flyway, gradlew

I've seen the other related posts for this topic, with none having an explanation for my problem unless I'm missing something. So, I'm developing a spring boot web app with 2 other developers. They are able to run the app locally, generate a war file, and connect to their local databases with no issues. However, I for some reason am not able to due to the following error report when I run the war file:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I am able to run a `./gradlew clean build` with a successful build, but I fail on `./gradlew bootRun`. This is a gradle project, where we are using the following flyway configuration to create our user, password, and db connection:

```
flyway {
    url = System.getenv('HW_DATABASE_URL')
    user = System.getenv('HW_DATABASE_USER')
    password = System.getenv('HW_DATABASE_PASSWORD')
}
```

I then check the .bashrc file, which is what I'm sourcing these values with, and each of the 3 fields has the correct values that I created. And then I run an `env | grep HW` command to confirm that the values do show up on the command line and are the ones being used, and they correctly do.

Here is the .bashrc file without the values being shown:
[image: bashrc]

Another interesting note is that all of this was working and I was able to run the app on my Mac prior to updating to Big Sur. After the update, this became the issue.

Any ideas from anyone here? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your project not able to get environment value of "HW_DATABASE_URL". Can you share how you're trying to pass?

Comment: @DhwanilPatel Yes here are my export statements in the .bashrc file without the values being shown. The url I use is the exact same that the 2 other developers are using, and they can't see the issue either.

Comment: @DhwanilPatel This also was all working prior to updating my Mac to Big Sur. After the update, this became the issue but I'm not sure why.

Comment: can you try gradle rebuild

Comment: @GvSharma Yes I've tried this and no solution from it.